# View Title does not filter correctly by userid

Tags: views

I'm very new to Drupal and trying to learn how to create a view that is filtered by userid, then by whether or not it's been published. I've created a content type of "Lists" and have a link on the home page called "My Lists." When the user clicks the link, it should open a view (and I have it set up as a page) and the title of the "page" should be "My Lists" and show each set of lists the user has. I.e., the user could have a list for their favorite movies, and another for their favorite books. Both lists should be shown UNDER the title of "My Lists" and the user would then click on which list they want to view or update.

What is happening though, is that somehow I got the Title "Booklists for " & "User" name in the title so it shows up as the main title for ALL lists instead of the correct title of "My Lists." I've gone to my Administration menu: Home » Administration » Structure » Views and under Views I have it set up as a Page. The Display name: Page - My Lists. The Title = Title: View My Lists. Now, when I scroll all the way to the bottom of the View My Lists (Content) it has a section for the Title with a little gear wheel icon that you're supposed to click on to change the Title. I've done that and the Page - My Lists: The title of this view dialog box comes up. I've changed the title in that section to "View My Lists" and set it to save for all displays. Then , it goes back to the Title and in the box showing for the title (that I just changed) it STILL shows "Booklist for Ayliea" when it SHOULD say "View My Lists."

It isn't changing the title.

Comment: Where did you set "Booklists for " & "User" name? Is it the title of a piece of content? Did you set the path settings to your menu item?

Comment: I set the booklist & username here: Home » Administration » Structure » Views at the bottom of the page for this there is a place to set the title and I tried to set it to "My Lists" but instead of displaying that in the title for the "page" View, it displays the previous "Booklist" for the userid. I never actually set any code. That's why I'm confused. If I did set it - I sure can't find where I set it now! I've been all through the Veiw properties and can not find any other place where the title for the View "Page" is set.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i guess this is difficult to solve from here. First you should check the following settings in your view.

1. Display name (how your Page-View is named, for administrative purposes, will not affect the frontend)
2. Title (this is the name of your view at the frontend, it can be overridden with contextual filters)
3. Path (this is the URL of your view)
4. This is the Title of your menu-item.

[image]

If this is all in order, you probably have overriden your view-title with a contextual filter.

Check these settings:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Volker. In the "Configure contextual filter: Content: Author uid", I have that set to "All Displays" - so if I'm understanding this correctly (and I definitely may not be understanding it!) this should NOT over-ride what the Title is set to. I have the section for "When the filter value is NOT in the URL" I have that set to "Provide default value" and "User ID from logged in user" So it should NOT be showing "Book Lists" on any one else's Lists view - only if the user has created on for themselves. I'm very confused. I am so new to using Drupal. Are there any tutorials for this?